# Matrix to power 30 using eigen values issue

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, matrix-exponential

> $$ \text{If matrix } A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \text{ then find } A^{30}.$$

I tried to approach through diagonalization using eigen values method.

I got eigen values as $-1, 1, 1$

As per diagonalization $ A = P*D*P^{-1}.$ So $ A^{30} = P*D^{30}*P^{-1}. $
But $ D^30 = I.$

So, $ A^{30} = P*I*P^{-1} = I $

But $ A^{30} $ is not equal to I. If we do general multiplication without all these.

Where is the mistake in my approach?

Comment: The matrix is not diagonalizable.

Comment: Then could you please tell me suitable approach to find A^30?

Comment: Hint  :jordan normal form

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have computed the eigenvalues of $A$ to be $\{-1, 1, 1\}$.  The repeated eigenvalue may be an obstacle to diagonalization.  In this case, the geometric and algebraic multiplicities of the eigenvalue $1$ are different, so A is not diagonalizable.  You continued as if $A$ were diagonalizable, so this is the mistake in your approach.

You have added a follow-on question in comments (instead of to your question, so you should not be surprised if other answers do not address it).  I see that others have demonstrated Jordan normal form and induction.  Another method is binary decomposition of the exponent and repeated squaring to get power-of-$2$ powers of $A$: \begin{align*}
A^1 &= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}  \text{,} \\
A^2 &= A^1 \cdot A^1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}  \text{,} \\
A^4 &= A^2 \cdot A^2 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 2 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}  \text{,} \\
A^8 &= A^4 \cdot A^4 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 4 & 1 & 0 \\ 4 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}  \text{,} \\
A^{16} &= A^8 \cdot A^8 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 8 & 1 & 0 \\ 8 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}  \text{,} \\
A^{30} = A^{11110_{\,2}} &= A^{16}\cdot A^8 \cdot A^4 \cdot A^2 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 15 & 1 & 0 \\ 15 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}  \text{.}
\end{align*}
Of course, after computing $A^4$ or $A^8$, perhaps one would notice the pattern...

There is a slightly faster way to get there using the above method.  $A^{-1}$ is easy enough to compute (using the minors method, for example).  $$
A^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$  Then, $A^{30} = (A^{15})^2 = (A^{16} \cdot A^{-1})^2$.  This replaces three multiplies with a multiply and an inverse.  Continuing to think about this leads to the computationally intractable problem of optimal [addition chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition-chain_exponentiation).

Comment: Thank you Eric. You cleared my doubt of why it was not diagonalizable

Comment: The last one with the inversion was a nice touch! Jordan-free, too.

Answer (score 4):

Since $A$ is not diagonalizable we can use Jordan form

\begin{align}
A^{30} &=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 2 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}^{30}
\begin{pmatrix}
1/4 & -1/2 & 1/2 \\
1/2 & 0 & 0 \\
-1/4 & 1/2 & 1/2
\end{pmatrix} \\
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 2 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 30 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1/4 & -1/2 & 1/2 \\
1/2 & 0 & 0 \\
-1/4 & 1/2 & 1/2
\end{pmatrix} \\
&= \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
15 & 1 & 0 \\
15 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

In another way

$$
\eqalign{
  & A = \left( {\matrix{
   1 & 0 & 0  \cr 
   1 & 0 & 1  \cr 
   0 & 1 & 0  \cr 
 } } \right)\quad A^{\,2}  = \left( {\matrix{
   1 & 0 & 0  \cr 
   1 & 1 & 0  \cr 
   1 & 0 & 1  \cr 
 } } \right)\quad A^{\,2n}  = \left( {\matrix{
   1 & 0 & 0  \cr 
   n & 1 & 0  \cr 
   n & 0 & 1  \cr 
 } } \right)  \cr 
  & A^{\,30}  = \left( {\matrix{
   1 & 0 & 0  \cr 
   {15} & 1 & 0  \cr 
   {15} & 0 & 1  \cr 
 } } \right) \cr} 
$$